# In tmux, is it possible to list all panes in all windows?

Tags: tmux

Say, I got two windows, Window 1 contains 2 pane (1, 2), Window 2 contains 3 panes(1,2,3), and I'm in pane 1 in Window 1, and I want to jump directly into the pane 2 in Window 2, `PREFIX w` which is `choose-window` will list all the windows in the session so I can jump into the right window, but it will not list the panes, `PREFIX q` which is `display-panes` will let me choose the right pane only in the current window, but not across windows.

So I wonder if there is any command that let me choose panes across windows.
The best solution is `choose-window` or a new command will not only list all the windows but also list all the panes inside each window like `tree` in a directory.

Comment: `list-panes -s` will show all the panes in the current server, but doesn't provide a way to choose one to make active. You can probably script something that takes this output and passes it to `choose-list`.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the `list-panes -s`, but according to the `CHANGES` file in [Github repo page](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/CHANGES), the `choose-list` has been removed, I'm using the latest version of tmux from git.

Comment: Sorry about that. I must have been looking at the man page on two different machines (one apparently out of date) while trying to find if there was a feasible answer.

Comment: (Note to self: `bind-key h choose-tree`, then use it with `C-b h`. It doesn't seem to conflict with any existing binding according to `C-b :list-keys`.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problems is solved by commit [aad4e4d](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/aad4e4ddb194cba9c01b0ddd696fb7b214e1a7eb) on github page several months ago, use `choose-tree` (just bind it to a key) to show all panes in all sessions/widows/tabs, it even shows a preview box when you scroll line into one pane from the list, very nice.

Just compile and install `tmux` from github source code and you can use this feature.

Answer (score 3):

The command is

```
tmux list-panes [-a|--all]
```

You can access this from within a tmux session with

```
<prefix>: list-panes -a
```

---

For example, if you need to pass a command to all panes that have `vim` running, you can do something like:

```
    tmux list-panes -aF "#{pane_id} #{pane_current_command}" |
    awk '/vim|nvim/ {print $1}' |
    xargs -I {} tmux send-keys -t {} "C-[" ":so ~/.vimrc" "C-m"
```

This command does the following:

- `tmux list-panes -aF "#{pane_id} #{pane_current_command}"` lists all panes across all sessions and windows, and for each pane, it prints the pane ID and the current command running in the pane.
- `awk '/vim|nvim/ {print $1}'` filters the output to only include lines where the current command is either `vim` or `nvim`, and then it prints the pane ID of those panes.
- `xargs -I {} tmux send-keys -t {} C-[ ":so ~/.vimrc" C-m` takes the pane IDs output by `awk` and for each pane ID, it sends the keys `<Esc>` (to ensure we're in normal mode), `:so ~/.vimrc` (the command to reload the vimrc file), and `<Enter>` (to execute the command) to that pane.

Answer (score 0):

Any item in this list, that return the format `<Session.pane_id>`:

```
tmux list-panes -aF "#S.#D"
```

can be used for `send-keys`:

```
tmux send -t '<Session.pane_id>' ls Enter
```